# How to convert a plain sql query with subqueries to use rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have tried converting this plain sql query to rails active record but I am unable to do so.

```
select vote_shares.election_year as vs_election_name,
   vote_shares.party as vs_party,
   (sum(vote_shares.party_seats)/totals.total)*100 AS vs
   from pcdemographics INNER JOIN vote_shares on vote_shares.pc_id = pcdemographics.pc_id,
   (
         SELECT vote_shares.election_name, sum(vote_shares.party_seats) as total 
         FROM `pcdemographics` 
         INNER JOIN vote_shares on vote_shares.pc_id = pcdemographics.pc_id 
         GROUP BY `election_name`
   ) AS totals
   where vote_shares.election_name=totals.election_name
   group by vote_shares.party,vote_shares.election_name;
```

This is what I have tried

```
@vssubquery = Pcdemographic.select('vote_shares.election_name, sum(vote_shares.party_seats) as total').joins('INNER JOIN vote_shares on vote_shares.pc_id = pcdemographics.pc_id')

Pcdemographic.select("vote_shares.election_year as vs_election_year,
   vote_shares.party as vs_party,
   (sum(vote_shares.party_seats)/'#{totals.total}')*100 AS vs").from(@vssubquery,:totals)
                        .joins("INNER JOIN vote_shares on vote_shares.pc_id = pcdemographics.pc_id and vote_shares.election_name='#{totals.election_name}'")
```

Comment: Can you share any approach you have tried so far?  Do you have `ActiveRecord` models like `VoteShare` and `Pcdemographic` in your rails project that can access the data?

Comment: Yes I have VoteShare and Pcdemographic models . Currently I have a Pcdemographic model that has an inner join on vote share with multiple filter scopes. However now that there is a subquery I am not sure how to access the inner value to perform the computation

Comment: I thought of using find_my_sql but then I need have scopes that i need to chain

Comment: Is there an error in your first column for `select`? Looks like maybe `vote_shares.election_year` should be `vote_shares.election_name` based on the alias `vs_election_name` and `group by` clause.

Comment: No i wrote the as statement wrong. I have tested this query in mysql and it returns what i want

Comment: The issue is that I need it as an active record relation and not as an array

Comment: Looks like you may want to look into the [active record `from` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from) for your subquery in conjuction with `joins`. I have never done this personally so I can't give any morespecific advice at this time.

Comment: If you post the code of your models and what you've tried so far, it will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324305/turn-sql-query-into-activerecord-relation

Answer (score 0):

My answer might not be what you hoped for but I recommend not using AR, use Sequel (http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) instead. It uses the concept of `Datasets` which I don't think has any equivalent in AR.

Disclaimer: Nobody asked me to advertise for it. I used both AR and Sequel and I found that Sequel is much better to perform complex queries and avoid the N+1 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`find_by_sql`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql) method?

Comment: Find by sql does not return an active record relation . I need it to return a relation so that I can chain scopes